# How to make a Flask API call wait until previous API is completed in Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a Flask app which has RFID read function API, when RFID read function API is called, the reader reads the data on the Card and returns the data. 
I want to program in such a way that, if two devices call the same API at the same time, one API must be executed and other API should wait until the previous API is completed.
How can it be done?

Comment: how would you define the 'same time'?

Comment: sending API call together twice